# Flutter: Get rendered text from content list

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to get all the publications of my WordPress page, and I have based using the following plugin.

This is my **JSON** code that is generated by the **WP REST API** plugin

```
[
  {
    "id": 65,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 1 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 1</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 1...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 650,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 2 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 2</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 2...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 3 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 3</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 3...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
]
```

More information about **WP REST API**:
https://v2.wp-api.org

**My code**:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:peluqueriafran/WebView.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('http://**********:88/WordPress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

  return new Post.fromJson(responseJson);
}

class Post {
    final int id;
    final String title;
    final String body;
    final String urlimagen;
    final String linkWeb;

    Post({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.urlimagen, this.linkWeb});

   factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return new Post(
         title: json['title']['rendered'].toString(),
      );
   }
}
```

**My error with screnshoot**:
[image]

**My questions is**:
How to select all publications with json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `json.decode(response.body)` returns a List, not a map.

For example

decoding JSON arrays([ ]) returns a List.

decoding JSON objects({ }) returns a Map.

Hence a List cannot be converted into a Map that's what the error says.

To resolve this do like this,
Since the outer list contains only one child you should do like this,

Wrong one

```
return new Post.fromJson(responseJson);
```

Correct way

```
return new Post.fromJson(responseJson[0]);
```